# Which line has an error in this for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

This question is from a python course on freeCodeCamp.com

```
smallest = None
print("Before:", smallest)
for itervar in [3, 41, 12, 9, 74, 15]:
    if smallest is None or itervar < smallest:
        smallest = itervar
        break
    print("Loop:", itervar, smallest)
print("Smallest:", smallest)
```

There is a mistake in one of these lines. I thought it's the fourth line because the variable 'smallest' is already written as None in the first line but it's not the right answer. Also, what type of value is None and what is it for?

Comment: Change the order of the numbers and see what happens.

Comment: just remove ```break``` from the code and it will work perfectly

Comment: @Chris - Did you just [vandalize](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306820/is-defacing-own-posts-worth-a-mod-flag) your question after an answer was posted?

Comment: nope, because I thought it was quite an embarrassing question to ask so I decided to change it and try to figure out the question myself.

Comment: @Chris - You can close, delete or communitize a question, defacing is not a tolerated option

Comment: ok, sorry cuz I'm new here. thx for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `break` on 5th line. It interrupts the loop which is not needed there.

Without it everything works okay.

> Also, what type of value is None and what is it for?

The `None` keyword is used to define a null value, or no value at all.

Comment: thx, it's the correct answer!